# PHP header(Location: ) stuck in redirection loop

Tags: php, header

I realize there are many question on PHP headers() however I could find nothing which specifically addresses my question based on my very simple piece of code.

**My Problem**

So I have this very simple block of code

```
 $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $profile = explode('/', $url);
    if ($profile[3] == 'index2.php') {
       // echo $profile[3] prints index2.php
        header('Location: profile.php');
        exit();
    }
```

As can be seen on the image below the code results in an infinite redirect loop.

when I set an absolute url like `header('Location: http://localhost:63342/mvc2.0/users/profile.php');` I still get the exact same problem. When I go incognito or use a different browser I still get same problem...

[image]

If anyone can provide me with some info or suggestions to what I am doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this your real code? If it means after echo you miss semicolon `;`.

Comment: profile.php redirecting to profile.php ? that would stuck you in redirection loop

Comment: sorry copy paste error

Comment: if your echoing something before header will not redirect you because output already sent to browser

Comment: @Demonyowh ok but the page is requested from index2.php, I might aswell remove that statement just tried it without and still same problem

Comment: `echo $profile[3]; //remove it`And`header('Location: profile.php'); //send to another page not to current page`.check it

Comment: can you please show us the profile.php code ?

Comment: no code issue just use your logic

Comment: @AlivetoDie just removed it, same problem

Comment: what code is there in profile.php

Comment: and do remove that exit() after header and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably simplify that to

```
$profile=basename( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
if ( $profile == 'index2.php' ) {
    exit( header( 'Location: profile.php' ) );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much -- Will read up on `basename()` function. Will accept when time expires